# Compare two tables using field map

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to compare the values between tables in two SQL Server databases.  The fieldnames in the tables in one database don't match the fieldnames in the tables in the second database.  I have a link table that has the matching table names and the matching field names mapped.

Table1:

```
| Tab1_ID | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|
|       1 | One    | Two    | Three  |
|       2 | Two    | Two    | One    |
|       3 | Three  | Two    | Two    |
|       4 | Two    | One    | One    |
```

Table2:

```
| Tab2_ID | Field_1 | Field_2 | Field_3 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|       1 | One     | Two     | Three   |
|       2 | Two     | Five    | One     |
|       3 | Three   | Two     | Two     |
|       4 | Two     | One     | Six     |
```

Link Table:

```
| LinkTab_ID | Tab1   | Tab2   | Tab1Fld | Tab2Fld      |
|------------|--------|--------|---------|--------------|
|        100 | Table1 | Table2 | Field1  | Field_1      |
|        105 | Table1 | Table2 | Field2  | Field_2      |
|        110 | Table1 | Table2 | Field3  | Field_3      |
|        124 | Table1 | Table4 | Field1  | Fieldname_01 |
|        166 | Table3 | Table5 | F3      | FN_3         |
```

Is it possible to use the Link Table to somehow specify the field names to compare between the two tables?

typically I'd do something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Tab1_ID = Tab2_ID
WHERE 
    Table1.Field1 != Table2.Field_1 
    OR Table1.Field2 != Table2.Field_2
```

However I have many tables and many fields and the fieldnames change (i.e. new fields).  My one constant is that the two are mapped in the link table.

The tables are one-to-one and fields are one-to-one.

Comment: You would need to generate your compare query dynamically using the link table and then run the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an approach you will need to expand it to suit. In particular you need a method for handling the join predicate(s).

also see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d697/2)

```
CREATE TABLE LinkTable
    ([LinkTab_ID] int, [Tab1] varchar(6), [Tab2] varchar(6), [Tab1Fld] varchar(6), [Tab2Fld] varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO LinkTable
    ([LinkTab_ID], [Tab1], [Tab2], [Tab1Fld], [Tab2Fld])
VALUES
    (100, 'Table1', 'Table2', 'Field1', 'Field_1'),
    (105, 'Table1', 'Table2', 'Field2', 'Field_2'),
    (110, 'Table1', 'Table2', 'Field3', 'Field_3'),
    (124, 'Table1', 'Table4', 'Field1', 'Fieldname_01'),
    (166, 'Table3', 'Table5', 'F3', 'FN_3')
;

CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Tab1_ID] int, [Field1] varchar(5), [Field2] varchar(3), [Field3] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Tab1_ID], [Field1], [Field2], [Field3])
VALUES
    (1, 'One', 'Two', 'Three'),
    (2, 'Two', 'Two', 'One'),
    (3, 'Three', 'Two', 'Two'),
    (4, 'Two', 'One', 'One')
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([Tab2_ID] int, [Field_1] varchar(9), [Field_2] varchar(9), [Field_3] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([Tab2_ID], [Field_1], [Field_2], [Field_3])
VALUES
    ('1', 'One', 'Two', 'Three'),
    ('2', 'Two', 'Five', 'One'),
    ('3', 'Three', 'Two', 'Two'),
    ('4', 'Two', 'One', 'Six')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @t1 AS NVARCHAR(30) = 'Table1'
DECLARE @t2 AS NVARCHAR(30) = 'Table2'
DECLARE @filter AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @filter = STUFF((SELECT ' OR ' + concat(Tab1, '.', Tab1Fld, ' <> ', Tab2, '.', Tab2Fld)
            FROM LinkTable
            WHERE Tab1 = @t1 AND Tab2 = @t2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,4,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM '
             + @t1 
             + ' INNER JOIN ' 
             + @t2 
             + ' ON '
             + @t1 
             + '.Tab1_ID = '
             + @t2 
             + '.Tab2_ID'
             + ' WHERE '+ @filter

select @query
--execute(@query)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d697/2/0)**:

```
| SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Tab1_ID = Table2.Tab2_ID WHERE Table1.Field1 <> Table2.Field_1 OR Table1.Field2 <> Table2.Field_2 OR Table1.Field3 <> Table2.Field_3 |
```